# recursive factorial function that prints to console on it's own (C#)

Tags: c#, recursion, console, factorial

This one is just to scratch an itch, and probably not even a problem worth solving on it's own.

I'd like to write a recursive factorial function to print to the console in C#.  The thing is, just out curiosity, I tried to get it to do this by only passing the function and argument.  As in, I'd like to avoid having to type `Console.WriteLine(Factorial(5));`

It's harder that I'd thought to just type this and get a result:

```cs
> Factorial(5);
```

here is the function I've been playing with:

```cs
int Factorial(int number)
{
    Console.Write(number != 1 ? $"{number} x " : $"{number} = \n");
    if (number <= 1) return 1; // end of the line
    number *= Factorial(number - 1); // recursive function
    Console.WriteLine(number);
    return number; // this could have been combined with line above, but more clear this way
}
```

the results come out like this, where instead of seeing the 2, 6 and 24.  I'd just like to see the 120:

```cs
5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 =
2
6
24
120
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what problem you have implementing "how to tell recursive function to skip some code"? It looks like you know how to write conditional statments (`if`) as well as able to pass parameters...

Comment: Personally I'd create two methods, `Factorial` which only prints the answer and `FactorialCalc` which only calculates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a local function as the actual recursive part, using the outer Factorial function as a wrapper which just calls it!

```cs
int Factorial(int number)
{
    static int DoFactorial(int number) => number <= 1
        ? 1
        : number *= DoFactorial(number - 1);
        
    var answer = DoFactorial(number);
    Console.WriteLine(answer);
    
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add an optional parameter to the function, indicating if it's an inner call, so the signature become

`int Factorial(int number, bool inner=false)`

outer call still use `Factorial(5)` normally, but inside, change

`number *= Factorial(number - 1);` to

`number *= Factorial(number - 1, true);`

then on printing the number, check if it's not inner, such as

`if (!inner) Console.WriteLine(number);`

Answer (score 1):

Performing side-effects inside a recursive function like calculating factorial is generally a terrible idea and what you are trying to do is something you really should not.

Get the answer, and then print it out in the calling code.

That said, here is a horrible way to achieve what you asked for. Please do not do this, I only offer this answer to show it is possible.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
            var frames = stackTrace.GetFrames();

            Factorial(5, frames.Length);
        }

        static int Factorial(int number, int frameCount)
        {
            Console.Write(number != 1 ? $"{number} x " : $"{number} = \n");
            if (number <= 1)
            {
                return 1; // end of the line
            }

            number *= Factorial(number - 1, frameCount); // recursive function

            var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
            var frames = stackTrace.GetFrames();

            if (frames.Length == frameCount + 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(number);
            }

            return number; // this could have been combined with line above, but more clear this way
        }
    }
}
```